# Make a Countdown based on real seconds passed (Like a Clock)

Tags: swift

I need to create a countdown that goes from 30 to 0, and when it reaches 0, go back to 30, also I need the seconds to be in relation of a real clock, for example, If I come back to the view (Even if I closed the app), I shouldn't be seeing the countdown always starting from 30, instead where it should be (In a range of 0-30) based on the time that passed.

The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
globalSeconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
print(globalSeconds)
```

The main issue that implementation has its that is based in 60 seconds, not 30. And the the values are for this example incrementing, and I need them to be decrementing.

Comment: If globalSeconds is an int, try doing print(globalSeconds % 30). But you will never see 30 as 30 % 30 = 0. If the real clock seconds are 40, you will see 10, then 9, ... 1, 0, 29, 28... 1, 0

Comment: globalSeconds % 30 did the trick, what is the % actually doing ? Limiting the reach to 30 ?

Comment: no, the % is the operator modulus, just like division or mutiplication. It returns the rest of dividing something by 30 in this case. So 30 % 30 = 0 because 30 / 30 = 1, rest 0. 31 % 30 = 1 because 31 / 30 = 1, rest 1

Answer (score 0):

You could create a date object 30 seconds in the future.
Then compare the current date to that object to figure out where the timer should be at.

I did this in a playground, you'd need to modify it for your specific requirement.

```
let futureDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(30).timeIntervalSince1970
var secondsLeft = TimeInterval(30)

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    secondsLeft = futureDate - Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    print(secondsLeft)
    if secondsLeft <= 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The output would also need some cleaning up

```
28.993669986724854
27.993721961975098
26.994149923324585
25.993762016296387
24.993871927261353
23.99389910697937
22.993980169296265
21.99391198158264
20.994942903518677
19.9939968585968
18.995089054107666
17.994417905807495
16.994072198867798
15.994122982025146
14.994197130203247
13.994181871414185
12.99530816078186
11.99462604522705
10.994287014007568
9.994328022003174
8.99430799484253
7.995084047317505
6.994402170181274
5.99443793296814
4.995491027832031
3.9945170879364014
2.9945571422576904
1.9946701526641846
0.9946119785308838
-0.005316019058227539
```